# How to encrypt a string with my SSH pubkey?

Tags: ssh, encryption

If I only have an SSH pubkey, how can I encrypt an ex.: IP address (so a short string), only using the ssh pubkey?

For decryption, the other party would have the pair of the pubkey, so the private key, with which it can decrypt the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do that:

First of all you should install the latest versions of OpenSSL and OpenSSH.

Before we can encrypt the plaintext with our public key, we must export our public key into a PEM format suitable for OpenSSL's consumption

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -pubout ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pem
```

then you can encrypt:

```
cat plain.txt | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pem > cipher.txt
```

- `rsautl`: RSA Utility
- `-encrypt`: key indicates we are encrypting from plaintext to cipher text
- `-pubin`: flag indicates we are loading a public key from `-inkey [public key file]`.

and for decrypt:

```
cat cipher.txt | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: although it sometimes request for ssh password many times.. any ide for that?

Comment: @Mhd Wissam Al-Roujoulah: any chance of seening the equivalent python code e.g. with PyCrypto or pyOpenSSL?

Comment: @ccpizza take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056762/rsa-encryption-and-decryption-in-python

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Helped me a lot because I am a bit newb at OpenSSL. I had a scenario where I wanted to store a password in a script, but didn't want to explicitly use my password because my scripts get backed up in various places.  I just wanted to mention I combined your two commands so I don't need a *.pem file. I did: 

cat plain.txt | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey <(openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -pubout) > cipher.txt

Comment: In my case, I didn't actually stream to cipher.txt.  I actually piped to base64, and used that hash to store my password in my PERL script.  Decryption is with a command like $pass=`echo "$password_hash" | base64 -d | openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey /home/myhomedirectory/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: On macos, the default `openssl` didn't like an argument after `-pubout` so this worked instead:

`openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -pubout > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.pem`